# integrate yui with javascriptmvc

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, yui, javascriptmvc

How to integrate yui with javascriptmvc?

I want to use yui3.Tabview in my application based on javascriptMVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's far better to ask questions on [JMVC's forum](http://forum.javascriptmvc.com/).  I answer questions there like crazy.  I only check StackOverflow once and a while.

Can jQuery listen to YUI events via bind?  If it can't integration is really easy, controllers should be able to listen to these events automatically.

If not, I'd build a special event wrapper for jQuery to listen to YUI's events.  Then you could listen to YUI events like:

```
".tab yui-addChild" : function(){}
```

I'd be happy to explore building this bridge with you on JMVC's forum.